# Applying for Australian Tourist Visa from US as an Indian Passport Holder

Tags: visas, australia

Following is brief details about myself:-

> Citizenship - Indian
>
> Current Residence - United States(F1 Visa - Student)

Following is the Plan of Travelling to Australia:-

> Going to India in December for vacations and then going to Australia
>   for 12 days from India and then coming back to India.

So, I have some questions regarding applying for Australian Visa:-

1. Can I apply for Australian Tourist Visa from the US? I think as now India has been added to the list in which we can apply online, so it should not matter where we apply from. Following is the link that contains the list of countries eligible for applying for Australian tourist visa online:-
   https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications#
2. Since I may have to go give some documents for showing finance, can I show bank statement of any of my accounts in India or US?
3. So, as of now, I have not any fixed address in US, since I am on internship these days and not in school. So, while filling the form, what is the address I should give? Should I give Indian address where my parents live? Or for current address - US address and Permanent address - Indian address?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I apply for Australian Tourist Visa from the US?

You can apply for an Australian visitor visa from anywhere.  As stated in the link you mentioned, as an Indian passport holder you can apply online.

> Since I may have to go give some documents for showing finance, can I show bank statement of any of my accounts in India or US?

You can upload any document you wish.  But note that bank statements may be used to determine whether, among other things:

1. you can afford the trip;
2. the money you have is sourced legally and genuinely; and
3. you have sufficient economic ties outside Australia to mitigate the risk of overstay.

While this is in the context of UK visas, [this article](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) may be helpful in understanding what bank statements do.

It should be noted that all documents you upload as part of an Australian visa application must be [certified](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/what-is-a-certified-copy-of-a-document) and translated (if required).  This may influence what sort of documents you can get certified in the US.

> So, as of now, I have not any fixed address in US, since I am on internship these days and not in school. So, while filling the form, what is the address I should give? Should I give Indian address where my parents live? Or for current address - US address and Permanent address - Indian address?

As you can see from the [paper version of the application form](https://www.border.gov.au/Forms/Documents/1419.pdf), it asks you for your *current* residential address.